# Make a boxplot in highchart with a date object in the x axis

Tags: r, highcharts, boxplot, axis-labels

I am trying to make a boxplot in highchart to include it in a shiny app, along with another graph I already have.

The problem is that boxplot, as far as I can tell, do not behave like other plots and when you map a date to the x-axis, it is treated as a character string, this mean: the plot display the entire date `ex: "2018-04-01"` an not `Apr'18` like it does in other plots.

Here I put a little reprex of what I have done

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)

# Data
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = rep(as.Date('2009-01-01') + month(1:12), times = 10),
  stock_price = rnorm(120, 0, 1)
)
```

```
# line plot
stocks %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise(mean_price = mean(stock_price)) %>%
  hchart(.,  
         type = "line", 
         hcaes(x = "time", 
               y = "mean_price"))
```

```
# Box plot first try
# hchart boxplot
stocks %$% 
  hcboxplot(x = stock_price, time) %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column")
```

After doing this first try, I try to create an abbreviated date and map it to the x-axis as follows, but the boxes are shown ordered alphabetically not chronologically

```
# hchart boxplot
stocks %>%
  mutate(month = month(time, label = T),
         year = str_extract(as.character(year(time)), "..$"),
         time2 = paste(month, year, sep = "'")) %$%
  hcboxplot(x = stock_price, time2) %>%         
  hc_chart(type = "column")
```

My desired output is a plot with x-axis like the line plot or like plotly's output

```
stocks %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~time, y = ~stock_price, type = "box")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `arrange()` and `fct_inorder()`, I believe I've achieved your desired outcome:

```
stocks %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(
    month = month(time, label = T),
    year  = str_extract(as.character(year(time)), "..$"),
    time2 = fct_inorder(paste(month, year, sep = "'"))
  ) %$%
  hcboxplot(x = stock_price, time2) %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column")
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Any way it would be good if the axis handle the object `time` as a date (Like in the line chart example), because when I plot more than two years the axis label do not fit very well.